# How to merge base64 png and preset png in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

Good day. I'm currently sending data from a form to a php script to save an image. It's sent via XMLHttprequest. The base image is retrieved via $_POST['img'] and is in base 64 format. The following PHP script saves it to the server and it works perfectly fine:

```
<?php

session_start();

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = "./gallery/" . bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)) . ".png";
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=camagru", "root", "admin");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `images` (`image`, `email`) VALUES (:image, :email)");
$sql->bindParam(':image', $fileName);
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->execute();

?>
```

The frame for the picture (Overlay) is sent to $_POST['frame'], but it's not a base64 image, it's a filename as follows: './frames/frame1.png'. How do I merge these two, and save it as $fileName?

Comment: Maybe useful https://www.google.nl/search?q=merge+two+png+images+php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to know how to merge base64 formats with png images.

Comment: You cannot merge anything in base64. You need the raw image data.